# Combinando bases de datos csv y transponiendo las observaciones

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, timeseries

Tengo una serie de tiempo que esta dividida en varios archivos csv individuales en los que cada uno contiene un mes de observación. No obstante estos están ordenadas de esta forma:

[image: excel]

Lo que hice fue pegarlos, pero se pegaron de forma descendente, yo necesito que se traspongan las fechas para que sea continua. Este es el script que utilice, si necesitan les puedo mandar el archivo.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

directorio =  "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/Trading IBKR OPTIONS/AMD_15_min"
extension = ".csv"

datos_combinados1 = pd.DataFrame()

archivos_csv = [archivo for archivo in os.listdir(directorio) if archivo.endswith(extension)]

for archivo_csv in archivos_csv:
    ruta_archivo = os.path.join(directorio, archivo_csv)
    datos = pd.read_csv(ruta_archivo, dayfirst=True)
    datos['date'] = pd.to_datetime(datos.iloc[:,0], format='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', errors='coerce')
    datos_combinados1 = datos_combinados1.append(datos, ignore_index=True)

#datos_combinados1 = datos_combinados1.dropna(subset=['date'])
datos_combinados1 = datos_combinados1.sort_values(by='date')

archivo_salida = "datos_combinados1.csv"
datos_combinados1.to_csv(archivo_salida, index=False)

print(f'Archivos CSV combinados y guardados en {archivo_salida}')
```

Como comentario final la celda donde se encuentra la fecha es tipo objeto y tiene la siguiente forma: `04/01/2010  07:15:00 a. m.`

Al ejecutar el código no se transponen las observaciones. ¿Cómo puedo unir los archivos y que se transpongan de forma ascendente, de la primera observación a la ultima, hacia abajo pues?

Comment: Hola Eduardo, para aclarar, ¿Lo que quieres es simplemente que las filas del  dataframe final (y por tanto del csv) queden ordenadas de acuerdo a la columna `date` de la mas antigua a la mas moderna? Otra cosa, ¿se te parsea correctamente la columna `date`  a tipo `datetime64[ns]` (`print(datos_combinados1["date"].dtype)`) o  terminas con `NaT`? Lo digo mas que nada porque `%p` depende de la localización particular y tu cadena es `a. m`.

Comment: Seria de ayuda que agregaras unas cuantas filas (con dos o tres es suficiente, siempre que muestren el problema que tienes) de un par de tus archivos y la salida esperada para ese caso a la pregunta. Pegalas como texto para facilitar la reproduccion, si tienes problemas con el formato no te preocupes, tu pega literalmente el contenido y ya te ayudaremos a formatear la pregunta.